# Make ViewPager snap with shorter drag

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gesture

Is there any way to make the support package ViewPager snap to the next page with a shorter drag? The default behaviour seems to be that even if I drag almost 75% the page still snaps back to the previous page when I let go. I'd like to make the snap threshold shorter and make the ViewPager snap to the next page instead.

Note that this applied to drag gesture. A fling gesture requires much shorter gesture already.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this ad-hoc, without worrying too much about the internals of ViewPager as long as you want to increase the target zone:

```
private class MyPageChangeListener implements OnPageChangeListener {
    private float mLastPositionOffset = 0f;
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if(positionOffset < mLastPositionOffset && positionOffset < 0.9) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        } else if(positionOffset > mLastPositionOffset && positionOffset > 0.1) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position+1);
        }
        mLastPositionOffset = positionOffset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, although I think it feels a little bit strange

Comment: please notice that, OnPageSelected will be called twice.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these values are hard-coded in a private method, so there's no simple way to override them.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#2075

Comment: Correct, but the values aren't 0.4/0.6f (as they're truncators). I *think* it works out to be 60% of the ViewPager width for both directions.

A fling only needs to be 25 dips, with a 400 dip/s velocity.

Comment: @ChrisBanes Of course you're right, I had just a very quick look at it - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code used in [Librera Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobnix.pdf.reader)

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

  public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initMyScroller();
    }

    private void initMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext())); // my liner scroller

            Field mFlingDistance = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mFlingDistance");
            mFlingDistance.setAccessible(true);
            mFlingDistance.set(this, Dips.DP_10);//10 dip short drag

            Field mMinimumVelocity = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mMinimumVelocity");
            mMinimumVelocity.setAccessible(true);
            mMinimumVelocity.set(this, 0); //0 velocity

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e(e);
        }

    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            super(context, new LinearInterpolator()); // my LinearInterpolator
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 175);//175 duration
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 1):

I did this using reflection. By setting a private field `mMinimumVelocity` to `-1`, you make the ViewPager take all your scrolls as a fling scroll - which needs much shorter drag to switch to the next page. Works like a charm!

```
Field mMinimumVelocity;
mMinimumVelocity = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mMinimumVelocity");
mMinimumVelocity.setAccessible(true);
mMinimumVelocity.set(mPager, -1);
```

The source code from which I know the private fields is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/jb-dev/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java).

Also if you want to make the threshold a little bigger than the default 25dp of the fling scroll, you can set the `mFlingDistance` field to some higher value, e.g. 45dp. But remember it also affects the required drag distance of the actual fling scroll.

```
Field mFlingDistance;
mFlingDistance= ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mFlingDistance");
mFlingDistance.setAccessible(true);
mFlingDistance.set(mPager, (int) (45 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
```